# How to get text from the xpath when using findelements

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

i am tying to use findelements to get all the text into one object and then see if a string is present in the list or not

```
Browser_Launch("chrome");
        sign_in();
        String a = null;
        Element_to_be_clicked("xpath", "//*[@id='history-guide-item']/a");
        List<WebElement> text = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ol[@class='item-section']//li//div//a"));
        for (int i = 0; i < text.size(); i++) {
            a = text.get(i).toString();
            System.out.println(a);
        }
        if (a.contains("Will & Grace - Back This Fall")) {
            System.out.println("test passed");
        } else {
            System.out.println("test failed");
        }
```

Website: Youtube
page: history

test: trying to get all the name of the videos present in history page to a object so that i can assert

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to declare `a` as list of string like: `List<String> a = new ArrayList<>();`

Secondly, since `text` is a `List<WebElement>` you should get the text of the web element and then compare the `getText()` of the link of anchor tag.

So instead of `a = text.get(i).toString();` it should be `a.add(text.get(i).getText());`. This way we are adding all video name to a list.

**Updated code:**

```
    Browser_Launch("chrome");
    sign_in();
    List<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
    Element_to_be_clicked("xpath", "//*[@id='history-guide-item']/a");
    List<WebElement> text = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ol[@class='item-section']//li//div//a"));
    for (int i = 0; i < text.size(); i++) {
        a.add(text.get(i).getText());
        System.out.println(text.get(i).getText());
    }        
    if (a.contains("Will & Grace - Back This Fall")) {
        System.out.println("test passed");
    } else {
        System.out.println("test failed");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing nothing inside the loop, try this:

```
Browser_Launch("chrome");
        String textToFind = "Will & Grace - Back This Fall";
        boolean isTextPresent = false;
        sign_in();
        Element_to_be_clicked("xpath", "//*[@id='history-guide-item']/a");
        List<WebElement> text = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ol[@class='item-section']//li//div//a"));
        for (int i = 0; i < text.size(); i++)
        {
            if (text.get(i).toString().contains(textToFind))
            {
                isTextPresent = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (isTextPresent)
        {
            System.out.println("test passed");
        } else 
        {
            System.out.println("test failed");
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but

List<WebElement> text = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ol[@class='item-section']//li//div//a"));

it is storing the Xpath in side the text Object not the actual text

Answer (score 0):

This xpath (`//ol[@class='item-section']//li//div//a`) is wrong.

change it with `//a[@dir='ltr']`